# spacing and justified wrapping of extra-long radio button labels with label-for markup

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist, word-wrap, label-for

ASP.NET renders a list of radio buttons as rows in table with inputs in the cell, like this:

```
    <table id="sites">
    <tr>
        <td>
           <input id="sites_11" type="radio" name="sites" value="1583" />
          <label for="sites_11">This is a very long site name including city and state</label>
         </td>

    </tr>
          .
          .
          <snip>
    </table>
```

I am trying to create some space between the input ( ) and its label so that this crowding

```
    ( )This is the beginning of a long label
```

becomes this:

```
    ( )  This is the beginning of a long label
```

Also, since the labels are very long, and many of them wrap, I'd like to have the wrap not extend beneath the (). I'd like it to look like this:

```
    ( ) This is a very long label for the site which includes
        the city and state
```

not like this:

```
       ( ) This is a very long label for the site which includes 
       the city and state
```

How is that achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a CSS class and apply it to your radiobuttonlist, with a label sub-class that contains your desired formatting. Something like:

```
.yourradioliststyle label {
padding-left:5px;
```

}